# javascript json post using variables

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get an Xmlhttp.response from a website, specifically with this part of code:

```
var apiUrl = "http://somesite/someapicall/correctapiKey";
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST", apiUrl, false);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var data {
    "username": username,
    "password": hashedPass,
    "someOption": "true",
    "someOtherOption": "true"
}
xmlHttp.send(data);
var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
var parsed = eval('(' + response + ')');
```

If i put in the actual strings in "username": & "password" instead of using the variables the code does work. with the variables it fails.

I'm probably missing something small again, but i really can't see it and i'm breaking my head over it since this afternoon :(

anyone ? please...

edited: the username and the hashed pass are given as variables with known correct values. changed the code to reflect the use of the variables

Comment: Just look at how markdown renders your code... You missed a quote mark...

Comment: You can't unless it's jsonp. Look up [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: You're also missing an `=` in your assignment of `var data`.

Comment: at which browser you are running this code

Comment: Also, not the reason it's failing but [don't use `eval()` to parse JSON](https://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/).

Comment: the quotation mark was a mistatke in posting the question, changed. same thing with the = ,oversight when posting the question, also edited.it's running in chrome under the ripple emulator for phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
 var apiUrl = "http://somesite/someapicall/correctapiKey";
```

uses an absolute URI, which implies you may be performing a cross-origin request. Make sure you aren't going to run into problems with the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).  (See also [ways to circumvent it](/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)).

---

This:

```
var data {
    "username": username,
    "password": hashedPass,
    "someOption": "true",
    "someOtherOption": "true"
}
```

… is a syntax error. You need an `=` sign after `data`.

If the last two options are supposed to be booleans, they shouldn't have quotes around them.

You should avoid automatic semi-colon insertion. Put a `;` after the `}`.

---

This:

```
xmlHttp.send(data);
```

… will convert `data` to a string by calling `toString()` on it. This will give you `[Object object]`.

If you want to send JSON, then you must convert the JavaScript object to JSON:

```
data = JSON.stringify(data);
```

---

This:

```
var parsed = eval('(' + response + ')');
```

is evil, slow, hard to debug and potentially dangerous if you get an expected response. Use a JSON parser instead:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
```